# Redis - very large single record (hash table)

Tags: hash, redis, time-complexity, hashtable

We have a huge dispute in here:

We have Redis installed on the server and we want to save a few types of data in it:

1. Some sporadic variables (for every user - so not just a few records)
2. A very large table **that will grow over time**

**The dispute is how to save the mentioned table**

We all know that Redis GET time complexity is O(1) - so we can store every record of the table as a record in Redis (with some prefix to know it's that table row)

OR

We can store the table as a single record inside Redis as a hash - and then access the row we want inside the hash - that's two O(1) steps.

I think that a huge ever growing SINGLE record inside Redis is catastrophic, but I need more than my opinion about it - I need a Redis expert response that will point the finger at the faults in that method or will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's clear something up - both [GET](https://redis.io/commands/get) and [HGET](https://redis.io/commands/hget) are O(1) operations. There is no time complexity difference between the two.

The next thing to think about how you may partition your keyspace later on. Let's say you have an explosion in growth and you need to cluster somehow (Enterprise, OSS, or whatever). In all of these implementations, you can't split up a key. So, if you just have a hash called `users` then a field that represents the user ID, that hash, as you mentioned will get very large and it won't be easy to scale.

A better take would be to partition your users into sub-hashes. Let's say you have user IDs that look like this: `1234` then what you would do is have a hash `user:12` and a field of `34` where you store your data for user `1234` (`HGET user:12 34`). This way you can save on keyspace overhead and still be able to partition your keyspace. This tactic is outlined in the [Redis Memory Optimization](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) document.

As far as your data, you can either do some sort of serialization and store everything in one field (JSON, CSV, etc.) or use hashes for each piece of data for each user and still partition (e.g. key `user:name:12` / field `34` and `user:age:12` / field `34`).

Comment: I think you got me wrong somehow  -  the focus is about the table (which has nothing to do to user properties - I only mentioned the user properties to show that Redis will hold other  properties that are not related to the table). The question is about the table - is it logical to place a whole table in one Redis record - the table is growing over time, that sounds like a bad practice...

Comment: To access some desired row in the table - won't it retrieve the whole table and then access it (yea it's o(1) but after a huge memory usage..?)

Comment: @Eking Redis has no concept of "table." It's an important conceptual part of the Redis data model.

Having one giant key is a bad practice as mentioned above for purposes of partitioning and clustering, but otherwise the size is actually irrelevant. As far as time complexity, the size of the hash has no bearing. It's all pointers internally, so Redis doesn't actually do anything with the rest of the hash if you only request one field. O(1) is O(1).

Multiple keys instead of multiple fields in hash is OK but the the keyspace creates storage overhead - but it's still O(1).

Comment: As I mentioned, it's well understood that the action of retrieving (and setting) the value in Redis is O(1).

Comment: I questioned the length of this "direct" (o(1)) action - although it's o(1), we'll need to retrieve a giant data block (Redis GET -> table_key) and only then to Search the row in the table which will be stored as a hash set, so this action will also be O(1) - but after we GET a giant value from Redis. loading a large data block (which you accessed directly still takes a lot more resources than a small block)

Comment: @Eking I've read your comments a few times and having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. 

Maybe some examples of what you're trying to do? Your referencing "table"/"row"/"search"/"record", which appear to be important to what you're asking but they aren't concepts in Redis, so it's hard to understand what you're getting at.

Maybe some examples of what you're trying to do?